# Accumulate Specific editable shapes on Specific points on a mesh line with no gaps

Tags: node-editor, geometry, geometry-nodes

I see lots of info on the accumulate geometry node when using random sized objects and aligning them tightly together. But I can't see to find any info on stacking specific objects that are put in specific points on a mesh line. I also need to be able to dynamically change the instance dimensions in sockets I will expose in the geometry node.

I need to be able to instance several items on the line but still dynamically edit the items dimensions. Its just like stacking the random sized boxes but I need to control each box individually too and keep the tight stacking.

Accumulate Question...

Frame 01... So I can put objects on a mesh line at specific points... (not sure if there is an easier way)...

[image: Frame 01]

Frame 02 - Accumulation works but not if I change the size of the cube.

[image: Frame 02]

Frame 03 - Wrong attempt at trying to get specific shapes in specific spots on the Mesh Line to accumulate and tuck up to each other but again it wont work if I change their size  Also, that ico sphere is getting some overlap from the other shapes it looks like.

[image: Frame 03]

How can I line up specific parts on the line AND have them editable and stay tight next to each other.??? Thanks for your help...

EDIT:

This is my basic set up how all the boxes need to be editable and how I'm attaching them to the mesh line in specific order. With one item having a switch (possibly the switch will be replaced for a scale to zero). I just wanted the accumulate to control the line and to keep everything tight together as the sizes are edited on the right.

[image: Frame 04]

Comment: I have two questions: Do the objects always follow the same sequence or do you ultimately want them to be randomly distributed?  Secondly are all the objest convex? in both cases there is a way to achieve wanted result but it is significantly harder. Will post answer in a few hours...

Comment: They will basically be boxes of various editable dimensions and will always be in a line in the same direction and sequence yes. Only variable is one in the middle will have a switch to be included or not. So it will need to collapse to the space with it or without. thx

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kiSi0HC7-aM&ab_channel=JohnnyMatthews would this not work?

Comment: jst-kiko - No - I watched all 5 parts of that series and that's how I got this far but it's no go. He generates random shape sizes in all of it so it's not the same set-up at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you want but this is the basic idea.

[image]

So we start by creating a random field. Then we re-scale one of the values, after  that we accumulate field and use it to set origin position and scale of the cubes.

The scale at index node group:

[image]

The frame produces a field full of 1 except at the selected index which is controllable. If you want to dynamically delete multiple cubes just repeat this node.

[image]

edit are you looking for something more like this?
red cubes are editable and are randomly instanced on line.

[image]

[image]

The picture of a island size node.
[image]

Comment: This looks interesting... I'll see what this does but I need one cube to be present or not but I need all the other cubes to be editable and have the stack update - I'm not sure this approach does that. Or can I edit all the other cubes too? I need to look closer at it. I don't need any random fields either since nothing will be random or is that needed as part of the setup?

Comment: my bad this node woun't allow you to edit independent cubes. I have also tried to make something like that but the nodes are starting to look crayzie

Comment: Added an example of what i think you want to achieve? the nodes are kinda complex and i don't have time to explain them today.

Comment: Thanks... 
I simply want to stack a row of like 6 boxes in a line. Have sockets for all of them to edit size and have the size automatically keep the boxes tight to each other. The second box will have a switch to be included or not. Nothing randomly scaled or placed at all. The order of the boxes will always stay the same just the one box in slot 2 will be present or not. I thought the accumulate was for this purpose. It seems like it may be easier to just string a bunch of add this width to this width and not even bother with the mesh line or placing the individual instances ugh

Comment: If you want 6 independent boxes I dont relay see a reason to use geometry nodes.

Comment: The main reason was to keep them editable and I had planned on scaling the line to stretch out the gap as needed and also to use a bounding box on the whole set up to move and center it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135564/discussion-between-jst-kiko-and-uncommon-blend).